# Grouped Time Restricted Demand Regression with value cap

Tags: machine-learning, regression, feature-engineering, preprocessing, distribution

so I am working on quite an interesting regression task that I haven't encountered before.

Our company sells products (steel) in tons. We offer contracts where the customer orders a certain amount of steel e.g. 20 tons over a specific time frame e.g. May - September. The customer pays upfront (cheaper) and can then ask to get a subset of his total volume delivered when its needed.

This leaves us with the following data per contract per customer:
| Contract ID | Quantity Delivered | Total Quantity | Month         | Start    | End
| ----------- | ------------------ | -------------- | ------------- | -------- | ---
| contract1   | 2                  | 20             | May           | May 2023 | September 2023
| contract1   | 8                  | 20             | June 2023     | May 2023 | September 2023
| contract1   | 0                  | 20             | July 2023     | May 2023 | September 2023
| contract1   | 7                 | 20             | Ausgust 2023  | May 2023 | September 2023
| contract1   | 3                  | 20             | September2023 | May 2023 | September 2023

I want to predict the demand for the remaining months for running contracts. Main focus on new contracts and contracts that are in the first few months.

My question is less about feature engineering but more about which type of task this is in general. I am not even sure regression is correct.

My current approach is to generate variations of each contract at the different stages (month).

e.g. above contract-var2 meaning we know the data of the first two months

| Contract ID | Quantity Delivered | Total Quantity | Month | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| contract1-var2 | 2 | 20 | May | May 2023 | September 2023 |
| contract1-var2 | 8 | 20 | June 2023 | May 2023 | September 2023 |
| contract1-var2 | 0 | 20 | July 2023 | May 2023 | September 2023 |
| contract1-var2 | 0 | 20 | Ausgust 2023 | May 2023 | September 2023 |
| contract1-var2 | 0 | 20 | September2023 | May 2023 | September 2023 |

I do that for every contract. Then I use a Random Forest with gridsearch. Of course I add other features like lagged quantities, month since start, etc....

But my main question is if this is a meaningful way to preprocess the data or if there are more suitable approaches for this kind of data. I never had to work with a regression task like that.

Also, how would I transform the data to be suitable for neural networks. It kinda has a time component but its not really a forecast.

Appreciate any help, ideas or suggestions on how to approach this task.

best,
M